# Drupal webform inside body of page?

Tags: drupal

I'm new to drupal but an expert in PHP etc.

I've got a page with some content and a webform. I want to be able to specify the location of the webform INSIDE the content

[content][content][webform][content] etc

It looks like the default placement for the webform is at the bottom of the page. Is there a tag or some php code that I can use to render it at a custom location inside the body of the page. I want the page contents to be editable by the user. The look and feel of the form is fine, changing the theming doesn't help here. (At least not as far as I can tell.)

Comment: You could do some css magic or put a block underneath the form, but those are both workarounds.

Comment: Are the pieces of [content] in different fields of the content type or in the body of the content type?  Why would you want the content to be editable by the user?

Comment: may be http://drupal.org/project/nodeasblock can help you if you are using drupal 6. or you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112194/drupal-webforms-as-block-modifying-action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do would be to add a description to the final field of the form if you only need to add text below it, though it might not be the size you want. Or you could override the theme:

In D6, use theme_webform_element() theme function in your theme to override the theme's template.php

In D7, use theme_webform_element_wrapper() theme function in your theme to override the theme's template.php

Use the Theme Developer Module, http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer which works like Firebug to identify where to modify the theme.